# Assign user profile subtype in Office 365

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, user-profile, office-365

Is there a way to assign a user profile subtype to a new userprofile in SharePoint 2013 Online (Office 365)?

This can be done by hand in the admin center of Office 365.
However, in this case my client has 20k+ users, divided into two categories.

Both need to have their proper userprofile subtype assigned to make sure they can see the appropriate profile fields.

In my case the user licenses are already assigned by Powershell, would this be possible through Powershell as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a manual job as far as I know in SPO. On premise you can use PowerShell.

Comment: Maybe any other way to accomplish the same? My scenario contains two different sets of users (with 20k+ users in total), with their own subset of profile values. I cant get my head around the fact that this automation scenario is unique in the 'Office 365 world'

Comment: Since there introduction, UP Subtypes have not been enhanced. If you need to use them, you have to suffer with this limitation. Can you describe the business case, maybe there is another solution.

Comment: The businesscase is that there are students and employees within the environment, where employees have different profile fields (not just extra fields). The best I can think of is hiding specific sections and/or fields with javascript based on the value in the function field (query SP with the javascript object model).

Comment: That's a great use for subtypes, but the management is painful.

Answer (score 2):

The [SharePoint Online PowerShell Module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364(v=office.15).aspx) is extremely limited.  As for CSOM, it seems that the `UserProfiles` [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userprofiles(v=office.15).aspx) does not include any classes or methods to set the subtype.